# CloudFormation - User Data run as Ubuntu user

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have the following user data in my CFN template:

```
  UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': 
      !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo apt-get update;
        sudo apt-get upgrade -y;
        sudo apt-get -y install python-pip;
        sudo apt-get -y install gcc;
        sudo apt-get -y install gcc-c++;
        sudo apt-get install awscli -y;
        sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb;
        echo "$(pwd)" >> /home/ubuntu/current1.txt

        cd /home/ubuntu/;
        echo "$(pwd)" >> /home/ubuntu/current2.txt
        pip install apache-airflow;
        pip install celery==4.4.0;
        pip install kombu==4.5.0;
        echo "$(pwd)" >> /home/ubuntu/current3.txt
        cd /home/ubuntu/airflow/;
        echo "$(pwd)" >> /home/ubuntu/current4.txt
        mv airflow.cfg airflow.cfg.original_1;
        cd /home/ubuntu/;
        nohup airflow initdb;
        nohup airflow webserver -p 8080 >> webserver.log &;   
        nohup airflow scheduler >> scheduler.log &;
        nohup airflow worker >> worker.log &;
```

If I do `cd /home/ubuntu` and then if install apache-airflow it is still getting installed under root.

I want to install the apache-airflow under `/home/ubuntu`.

How to install packages under `/home/ubuntu` user ?

Comment: I wonder whether you can set `export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow/`? See: [Quick Start — Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation when automating the installation of Ghost on an Ubuntu instance.  You can try switching users.  I would have to test this when attempting to install a package using pip specifically.  But here is an example of how I had to run some specific setup commands as a non-root user:

```
su ghost-user << 'EOF'
cd /ghost-app/ghost
ghost install --no-setup --no-stack --dbhost 10.16.11.80 --dbuser ghost --dbpass myterribledbasepassword --dbname ghost_prod
EOF
```